# ayuda con Menu de navegacion

Tags: html, css

Hola espero estén bien :)

tengo un menú desplegable que hice con html y css,  pero quiero acomodar los menús  de forma que se expandan por toda la pantalla del diseño.

por ejemplo,este es el menú despegable que tengo.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
quiero que sea como la siguiente imagen 
que se mire de esta forma que los menús 
de la barra se expandan por el diseño azul de la pantalla.
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
a continuación les dejo el código CSS y html

```css
body {
     padding: 0;
     margin: 0;
    }
    ul {
     margin: 0;
     padding: 0;
     list-style-type: none;
     background: #1b4f72;
     position: relative; 

    }

    ul li {
     display: inline-block;
     
    }
    ul li a {
     color: lightgrey;
     text-decoration: none;
     padding: 15px;
     display: block;
    }
    ul li:hover {
     background: #0a1445;
    }
    ul ul {
     position: absolute;
     min-width: 200px;
     background: #0a1445;
     display: none;
     
    }
    ul ul li {
     display: block;
     background: #0a1445;
    }
    ul li:hover ul {
     display: block;
    }
    ul li i {
     color: #0a1445;
     float: right;
     padding-left: 5px;
    }
    nav div {
     background: lightgrey;
     color: #0a1445;
     font-size: 24px;
     padding: 0.6em;
     cursor: pointer;
     display: none;
    }
    @media(max-width: 768px) {
      nav div {
       display: block;
      }
      ul {
       display: none;
       position: static;
       background: #e3e3e3;
      }
      ul li {
       display: block;
      }
      ul ul {
       position: static;
       background: #e3e3e3;
      }
    }
```

```html
<html>
  <head></head>
  <body>
     <nav> 
      <div>
       <i class="material-icons">menu</i>
      </div>
      <ul  class="nav">
       <li><a href="MDIPRUEBA.HTML">Inicio</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">Registro</a>
        <ul>
         <li><a href="#">Ingreso de Expediente</a></li>
         <li><a href="#">Busqueda de Expediente</a></li>
        </ul>
          </li>          
       <li><a href="#">Tramitaciones </a></li>

          <li><a href="#">Reportes</a>
        <ul>
         <li><a href="#">Reporte Mensual</a></li>
         <li><a href="#">Reporte Trimestral</a></li>
         <li><a href="#">Reporte Anual</a></li>
        </ul>
          </li>
       <li><a href="#">Mantenimiento</a>
        <ul>
         <li><a href="#">Usuarios</a></li>
        </ul>
          </li>
       <li><a href="alerta.php"> Alerta        
       <i class="material-icons">add_alert</i>        
        </li>
       <li><a href="#">Cuenta</a>
        <ul>
         <li><a href="#">Configuracion General</a></li>
         <li><a href="#">Cerrar Sesion</a></li>
        </ul>
          </li>       
      </ul>
     </nav> 
  </body>
  </html>
```

gracias por sus respuestas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aplicando los siguientes estilos debería conseguir el efecto que quieres

```
.nav{ 
    display: flex; 
    width: 100%;
    justify-content: space-between;
}

.nav li {
    width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: gracias me sirvio de mucho :)

Answer (score 0):

Espero que aún te sirva mi pequeño aporte :D

### Tratando de arreglar un poco tu código el resultado quedaría algo así:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

---

**Tu código queda así:**

```css
  * {
     padding: 0;
       margin: 0;
       font-family: sans-serif;
       transition: all 300ms;
    }

    ul.nav {
     list-style-type: none;
     background: #1b4f72;
      position: relative;
      /*De Jeremy Fonseca*/
      width: 100%;
      display: flex;
      height: 60px;
      /* Espacio entre cada elemento */
      justify-content: space-around;
      /*Todo centrado*/
      /* justify-content: center; */
      /*Espacio entre cada elemento menos entre los extremos*/
      /*justify-content: space-between;*/
    }

    ul li {
      width: auto;
      height: 100%;
    }

    ul li a {
     color: lightgrey;
     text-decoration: none;
     padding: 15px;
      display: block;
      line-height: 30px;
   }

    ul li:hover {
     background: #0a1445;
    }

    ul ul {
     position: absolute;
     min-width: 200px;
     background: #0a1445;
     display: none;
    }

    ul ul li {
     display: block;
     background: #0a1445;
    }

    ul li:hover ul {
       display: block;
    }

    ul li i {
     color: #0a1445;
     float: right;
     padding-left: 5px;
    }

    nav div {
     background: lightgrey;
     color: #0a1445;
     font-size: 24px;
     padding: 0.6em;
     cursor: pointer;
     display: none;
    }

    @media(max-width: 768px) {
      nav div {
       display: block;
         }

      ul {
       display: none;
       position: static;
       background: #e3e3e3;
          }
          
      ul li {
       display: block;
          }
          
      ul ul {
       position: static;
       background: #e3e3e3;
      }
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
   <meta charset="UTF-8">
   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
   <title>Menú</title>
</head>
<body>

   <nav> 
      <div>
         <i class="material-icons">menu</i>
      </div>
      <ul class="nav">
         <li><a href="MDIPRUEBA.HTML">Inicio</a></li>
         <li><a href="#">Registro</a>
            <ul>
               <li><a href="#">Ingreso de Expediente</a></li>
               <li><a href="#">Busqueda de Expediente</a></li>
            </ul>
         </li>          
         <li><a href="#">Tramitaciones </a></li>
         <li><a href="#">Reportes</a>
            <ul>
               <li><a href="#">Reporte Mensual</a></li>
               <li><a href="#">Reporte Trimestral</a></li>
               <li><a href="#">Reporte Anual</a></li>
            </ul>
         </li>
         <li><a href="#">Mantenimiento</a>
            <ul>
               <li><a href="#">Usuarios</a></li>
            </ul>
         </li>
         <li><a href="alerta.php"> Alerta</a>      
            <i class="material-icons"><!--add_alert--></i>        
         </li>
         <li><a href="#">Cuenta</a>
            <ul>
               <li><a href="#">Configuracion General</a></li>
               <li><a href="#">Cerrar Sesion</a></li>
            </ul>
         </li>       
      </ul>
   </nav>
   
</body>
</html>
```

---

**By: Jeremy Fonseca**